# Exception raising does not reflect in test case even though raised as seen in logs

Tags: python, regex, testing, exception

I'm practicing TDD in Python and came across a problem in testing whether an exception is raised.

Here is my `test_phonebook.py` with `test_add_empty_name_raises_exception` which fails.

```
import unittest
import phonebook


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add_empty_name_raises_exception(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, phonebook.add, "", "1111111111")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

Below is my `phonebook.py` with the method `add` which adds the data into the dictionary.

```
import re

_phonebook = {}
file_name = "phonebook.txt"


def is_valid_name(name):
    return re.search(r"([A-Z][a-z]*)([\\s\\\'-][A-Z][a-z]*)*", name) is not None


def is_valid_number(number):
    return re.search(r"\+?[\d ]+$", number) is not None


def add(name, number):
    try:
        if is_valid_name(name) and is_valid_number(number):
            _phonebook[name] = number
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid arguments.", name, number)
    except ValueError as err:
        print err.args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

My problem is that the test fails even though it is seen in the console log that there was a `ValueError` raised within the `add` method.

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

('Invalid arguments.', '', '1111111111')
======================================================================
FAIL: test_add_empty_name_raises_exception (path.to.phonebook.test_phonebook.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\phonebook\test_phonebook.py", line 13, in test_add_empty_name_raises_exception
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, phonebook.add, "", "1111111111")
AssertionError: ValueError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s
```

How do I solve this? I there something I forgot?

I also tried using the new format for handling exceptions in tests in Python 2.7 but it still hasn't caught the `ValueError` raising.

```
def test_add_empty_name_raises_exception(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.phonebook.add("", "1111111111)
```

I also changed the form of the test case into using lambdas but still no changes.

```
def test_add_empty_name_raises_exception(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: phonebook.add("", "1111111111"))
```

I also cleaned my directory and restarted Eclipse Luna and problem still persists.

**Possible solution**

I was reading the [8.Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) documentation and got to the "[Raising Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)" part which states that:

```
If you need to determine whether an exception was raised but don’t intend to handle it, 
a simpler form of the raise statement allows you to re-raise the exception:
```

I added this to the existing `add` method as such:

```
def add(name, number):
    try:
        if is_valid_name(name) and is_valid_number(number):
            _phonebook[name] = number
            print "Added %s:\t%s" % (name, number)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid arguments.", name, number)
    except ValueError as err:
        print err.args
        raise
```

Which caused the test case to pass.

Is this the correct way? To call `raise` again in the `except` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you catch an exception (in your `except ValueError as err:` block), you prevent it from continuing back up the call stack to eventually terminate the program.  Essentially, you're saying "I know how to handle this, so no need to panic anyone else."

Re-raising an exception is the proper thing to do if you caught the exception but didn't do so to actually *fix* anything, for instance, to log that it occurred.  Typically, though, one catches an exception in order to correct it.

In your case, you're catching the exception almost immediately after you yourself raised it.  Why not put your logging statement in the same `else` block as the `raise`?  No need for a `try: ... except:` indent at all.

```
def add(name, number):
    if is_valid_name(name) and is_valid_number(number):
        _phonebook[name] = number
        print "Added %s:\t%s" % (name, number)
    else:
        print "Invalid arguments.", name, number
        raise ValueError("Invalid arguments.", name, number)
    return
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have some questions if you don't mind: (1) is this `if ... else` block with `raise` an equivalent or another best practice alternative to `try: ... except:`(2) what should I do if I need to test a `try: ... except` block? Is there an alternative for `self.assertRaises`? (3) Is `return` a requirement in all Python `functions` even though some of it are just `void` or does not return anything?

Comment: another one, I understand how exception handling work in basic terms so in my test case, how do I know in the test case that an exception has been raised without any logs, re-raising, just all in the spirit of confirming that an `exception` was raised?